# Better conversion functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have various classes in a C++0x framework and would like to write functions to convert between some of them. For example:

```
struct Foo { float v; };
struct Bar { int i; };
struct Tar { float p, q; };

void Convert(const Foo& x, Bar& y) { y.i = static_cast<int>(x.v); }
void Convert(const Tar& x, Foo& y) { y.v = x.p + x.q; }
```

This is just an example. There are quite a lot of "small" classes. And not all conversion functions make sense.

Additionally there are some classes which essentially behave like STL containers and should "inherit" these conversion functions.

```
void Convert(const std::vector<Foo>& cx, std::vector<Bar>& cy) { ... }
void Convert(const std::vector<Tar>& cx, std::vector<Bar>& cy) { ... }
```

No I am looking for an easy way to define theses functions. I tried:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
void Convert(const std::vector<X>& cx, std::vector<Y>& cy) {
   cy.resize(cx.size());
   for(std::size_t i=0; i<cx.size(); i++) {
     Convert(cx[i], cy[i]);
   }
}
```

and this works perfectly.

However with such a setup one has to write

```
std::vector<X> cx = { ... };
std::vector<Y> cy;
Convert(cx, cy);
// when not specifying the type, one needs to use this form f(X, &Y)
```

With a setup like

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
std::vector<Y> Convert(const std::vector<X>& cx) {
   std::vector<Y> cy(cx.size());
   for(std::size_t i=0; i<cx.size(); i++) {
     cy[i] = Convert(cx[i]);
   }
   return cy;
}
```

one has to write

```
std::vector<X> cx = { ... };
std::vector<Y> cy = Convert<X,Y>(cx);
// can I avoid specifying the source type with this form?
```

Of course at some point the target type need to be mentioned, but the source type is defined by the function parameter. I do not want to mention it again and again.

Is there a elegant generic way to handle such conversion functions?

**Edited the question for clarification**

Comment: Have you tried `Convert(cx, cy)`?

Comment: What I wonder is, why do you need all these small classes and small conversion functions? To me that almost seems like something is strange with the design.

Comment: @Danvil: http://ideone.com/pzRHa  I didn't change any of your code, it works fine.

Comment: @Danvil: As for the containers, `boost::transform_iterator` would have made those _really_ easy.

Comment: I'd like to add that typedefs can make your life easier here. Like... typedef std::vector<int> vecint; vecint a = { 4, 2, 1 };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out how to do this. By re-ordering the template arguments

```
template<typename Y, typename X>
std::vector<Y> ConvertTo(const std::vector<X>& cx) {
   std::vector<Y> cy(cx.size());
   for(std::size_t i=0; i<cx.size(); i++) {
     cy[i] = Convert(cx[i]);
   }
   return cy;
}
```

one can write

```
std::vector<Y> cy = ConvertTo<Y>(cx);
```

and the compiler automatically infers the second template type for input. Nice feature!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using ctors:

```
struct Bar {
   int i;

   explicit Bar(Foo const &f) : i(static_cast<int>(f.v)) {}
};
```

Then you can do:

```
Bar x = static_cast<Bar>(some_foo);
```

It may be open to question whether you really want to make the ctor explicit. If you eliminate it (allow implicit conversion) converting a vector becomes trivial:

```
std::vector<foo> foos;

// code to populate foos ...

std::vector<Bar> bars((foos.begin()), foos.end());
```

As to whether to make it explicit or not, the question is whether you're likely to get a conversion from Foo to Bar accidentally, letting something happen that you really don't want. That's a pretty common problem with things like conversion to `bool`, but much less often a problem with conversion from one user-defined type to another. That being the case, leaving the `explicit` off can be convenient and reasonably safe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use constructors for this purpose?

```
explicit Bar(const Foo& x) : i(static_cast<int>(x.v)) {}
```

Comment: That won't convert containers, and he may not be able to modify the classes.  This is a valid suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Because of **Return Value Optimization** you don't need to use an out parameter, just use return value:

```
void Convert(const X& x, Y& y);
```

becomes:

```
Y Convert(const X& x);
```

so now you can use it in expression.

Also consider using **converting constructors** or **conversion operators** instead:

```
Y::Y(const X&);
X::operator Y();
```

These will allow implicit conversion between types (if that is what you want - otherwise you can declare them explicit).

For handling STL containers use iterator ranges:

```
template<class FwdIterator>
Y Convert(FwdIterator begin, FwdIterator end);
```

In this style, it will not only be compatible with all of the STL containers, it will also be compatible with raw pointer ranges.

Also note if you declare implicit converting constructors or conversion operators than you can use std::copy:

```
vector<X> xs = ...;
vector<Y> ys;
copy(xs.begin(), xs.end(), back_inserter(ys.begin()));
```

This will call your user-defined conversions implictly when converting elements from xs to ys.

Comment: There may by more than one conversions for a type. So Y Convert(const X& x); does not work.

Comment: You mean more than one result type? (The input parameter overloads the function)  You can make different result types by (1) making it a type parameter `Convert<Y>(x)`, or; (2) adding type to function identifier, ie `Convert_Y(x)`; or (3) Using converting constructors or conversion operators.